# Send a Print Job to a Computer

Tags: .net, networking, printing, windows-7, asp.net-web-api2

So say I have a computer called `ServerA` and I want to have it send a print job to a printer queue on a computer called `WorkstationK`, is there a way to do that without networking the printer attached to `WorkstationK`?

NOTE:
I almost asked this over on SuperUser, but I am wanting to do this from a ASP.NET service, so solutions like "copy the file to the workstation...." does not work.

Use Case:
In case it matters, this is what I am wanting to do, I have an application that will take some input.  That input will be sent to the server (`ServerA`).  As a result of that input, I need to send a print job to a given computer, `WorkStationK` for example.  But it could be one of about 100+ computers.

So I don't want to setup all those all of those printers as "Network" printers.  Also, I don't want to install/create apps on/for the workstations (it is an easy app to write and I will do it if I have to, but I am hoping for a no-deploy solution)

Comment: When you say you want to send a "print job" from a server, what's exactly a "print job" for you? What's the source?

Comment: @SimonMourier - it would be a print to a label printer.  It is sent via normal windows print spooler when done on the computer directly.

Comment: What do you call "via normal windows print"? What API do you use? Or maybe you don't know yet?

Comment: @SimonMourier This is what I use when printing from a .net application: https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/89b7139186990b970e74c28083237918 .  But for this question, I am just looking for a way to add a print job to the print spooler on a windows 7 machine from a remote machine (on the same network).

Comment: If a workstation doesn't share its printer, I don't see how you could do that without installing a program on it? And you could reuse this code of yours in that program. Just invent a way to communicate between the server and the workstation in that program (socket, http, etc.)

Comment: *No installs on the workstation*: A big bounty would not help us giving you an inexistent solution. I'm afraid your requirement cannot be fulfilled in any way.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is probably not possible because if you think about it, it would be a real issue in terms of security/abuse. If a website could print stuff without confirmation on a local pc, this would be some serious madness. And for that reason there do not exist any interfaces to do this. If they do I would be astonished by it and please correct me!

Solutions that come to my mind:

- Just produce the page to be printed and let the user click "Print". Doesn't require installation and is probably not too much for the user.
- Write a small daemon service/application to be able to send the print-job to the computer that currently is connected to the service and the daemon handles the adding to the print queue.
- Deploy your service as something small and easy like a ClickOnce-App that should already suffice to be able to do this task. The user himself would be easily able to install it without privileges and one click. And it would even update itself so changes would be really easy to do/comparable to a web-app.

What you prefer is up to you but as stated above I don't think it is possible to do it completely remote.

Another possibility I didn't think through and certainly don't have enough experience with it, is something like Google Cloud Print or other services like this. Maybe adding this your company could be a pretty comfortable solution that would pay off in a greater perspective.

Comment: I agree that it is probably not possible.  Though since I am not running in a browser, it seems that it should be possible.  I may not have directly said it, but I am running in a Local Area Network.  It seems like there should be a way to do it over a network.  (From a browser, it would be really bad.  My Printer would start print ads at every site I visit.)

Comment: @Vaccano I searched a bit more and there might actually be a way to do it with Powershell. Actually there are probably more than one way to do it with Powershell especially if you can control them via a remote-shell/interface. But if these computers don't have any interface open to some kind of modification/administration I strongly doubt that it's possible, since there does simply not exist a native interface to control printers remotely (for the above mentioned good reasons).

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have the following architecture:

- Server with WebApp
- a large number of workstations, each connected to a close-by printer

### Use Case

As a use case I understand:

- The user uses a WebApp through the browser and at some point clicks a button that reads `print` or alike
- The server has to render the document to be printed
- The document is supposed to be printed from the workstation on the close-by printer

I see two possible options.

### Solution 1

The idea is that the button print not only sends the request to the server app but also generates the file (let's say in pdf format) and sends it back to the client's browser. If this is done within the Request by streaming the pdf file out as the response to the request, the browser would download the pdf file automatically.

The server code could look something like this (:

```
private void CreateImageAndReply(Src source)
{
    // render the output file using GhostScript or alike to 
    // a subdirectory that is accessible via http
    [..]
    // 
    Response.Redirect(DownloadFileUrl);
}
```

The subdirectory to render the file to from the WebApp has to be added through the IIS Manager via `add virtual directory` (see [image: Screenshot]) to enable the access from the browser.
The user would be left with the duty to open the file and print it through the system's print dialog.

#### Development Tasks

- Implement the rendering and Redirect
- Test against all used browsers

#### Deployment Tasks

- none

### Solution 2

The idea here is that the server can store the document in a directory accessible to this very client.

Once the print file is written, a job running on each and every workstation sees the new file and prints it (i.e. through the [Print](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB593q1uzMAhURyWMKHUyvAgwQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc775908(v%3Dws.10).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHqj2O1bdj8FmqTAjn4Pzq0qeXgKQ&sig2=qI5VRgk9g8BdBwd1ZWPXtg) command inside a console program or a batch file or a PowerShell file).

To manage the 100+ "PrintBoxes" you could use the ComputerName as a folder name from inside the task running on the Workstation side and inside the WebApp on the server side as well (i.e. by using [Environment.MachineName](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiX_96A2OzMAhUHy2MKHQaaDcUQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.environment.machinename(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEGCqDHhXHNjxM2TlQ_YlaYyc_YeQ&sig2=X3RX2pW3YdpPGSrS963B0Q&bvm=bv.122448493,d.cGc)). The WebApp could e.g. render the pdf file to c:\Printboxes\Desktop123\print0310.pdf. The client-side task could be started through the [TaskManager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-task-manager) e.g. at the beginning of the work day and poll the content of a mounted network directory, e.g. n:\Printboxes*.pdf; this local program would send any discovered file via the print command to the local printer and delete the file thereafter. It could also write a receipt file back to the directory (i.e. print0310.receipt) which would be accessible to the app WebApp on the server ... I think you get the idea.

As an alternative to the mounted network drive you might consider using sth like Dropbox on all the above mentioned machines (server and workstations) to synchronize the files back and forth in a secured way. This way, only the Dropbox-User (could be a free account; same user on the server and all the clients, no interaction of the user necessary).

#### Development Tasks

- Writing the rendering on the server plus the Redirect as mentioned above
- Writing a ConsoleApp that can be deployed to every client

#### Deployment Tasks

- Install/Copy cmd executable (small C# program)
- Schedule a task to run it at system start or user log-on
- Install Dropbox (with user)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've googled a lot, but just for the sake of adding info (since I can't comment yet :()

I think you will have to find a way to generate a SPL file, send the SPL file to the workstation, and prompt the workstation to print it.

**To generate a SPL File:**
You might check this out...  I know you don't want to install anything on the workstations, but this might help you grab the a SPL file of the print job.

http://www.lvbprint.de/html/splviewer1.html

Also, for some printers there are settings to capture the SPL file of a print job.  You might be able to be clever with a PDF printer (or something) on the server to capture the SPL file of a print that way?

**To send/print a SPL File:**

Sending should be easy enough, but I didn't see any super easy ways to print from a SPL file.  There's this...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179774

...but it requires a lot of intervention at the workstation level which may be difficult/impossible.  I don't know if simply dropping the SPL file directly into the default directory for the printer spool is enough to make it print.

Still looking...best of luck.

Comment: This guy seems to be doing something very similar but with PCL files.       http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/428371/ASP-NET-Printing-on-clients-side-directly-without

Comment: This is exactly (almost) what you are looking for.  This is a DLL (server side DLL) that that Crystal Reports uses to print directly to client side printers.  It includes methods to pull the installed list of printers from the client in case you want to parse the list to find a label printer.  It's not clear to me if this is Crystal Reports exclusive, or if you could use it to print anything.     http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-Directly-Print-Crystal-Reports-to-Default-Client-Printer-from-ASP-NET-without-Preview-or-Printer-Dialog/

Comment: They have other products to assist with this as well...     http://www.neodynamic.com/products/printing/raw-data/

Comment: This was good stuff, closest to working of them all, so I am going to give it the nod.

Comment: Glad I could be of mild assistance :)

Answer (score -1):

How would ServerA know which printer of WorkstationN use, if there is one ?

If these printer are network printer, you should be able to send the job directly to them over network. If they are "smart, last-gen printer" you could even send the document to print by email as attached files using the constructor stuff instead of creating your own app.

Comment: I would have a service call that would know.  I am not as worried about getting the printer name.  (I think there is a powershell call that can get the list of printers from a remote computer.)

Comment: Alas, the printers are not network printers.  They are label printers that are connected via USB (or parallel) to the computer.  I need a way to remotely add a print job to  the windows print spooler.

Comment: I have found a command for sending files (probably only text file) to a printer (local or remote). Hope it will help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731623(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Thank you for looking into this!  Unfortunately that document indicates that it must be a "Network Printer".

Comment: You should be able to execute script on a distant computer, then you could do a remote script which would start locally the printing operation. If the printer aren't shared I doubt you could work directly with them.

Comment: like @MarcoGuignard said, you could have your app send a request to the server and possibly the document u want to print. Then the server execute the print request. If at all, only the server needs to be networked to the printer. Why was this ans downvoted??